# dependent select box php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

im newbie and i have a problem that is cant call data for the second select, below are table and column for my database structure and code. Please give me a hand TQVM!

## table1 name - movie

id, movieid, moviename

## table2 name - movievenue

id, movieid, venueid, mvenue

### index.php

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){


           $("#movie").change(function(){
                 var movie=$("#movie").val();
                 $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"venue.php",
                    data:"movie="+movie,
                    success:function(data){
                          $("#venue").html(data);
                    }
                 });
           });
       });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    Movie :
    <select name="movie" id="movie">
      <option>-select your movie-</option>
    <?php 
    include "db.php"; 
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT movieid, moviename from movie order by moviename");
    while($movie=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    echo "<option value=$movie[moviename]>$movie[moviename]</option>";

    } ?>
    </select>


    Venue :
    <select name="venue" id="venue">
        <option>-select your venue-</option>
    </select>
 </body>
</html>
```

### venue.php (i wan to have 'mvenue' to show on the 2nd select box and its depend on 1st selection id which is 'movieid'.)

```
<?php
 include "db.php";

  $movie=$_POST["movie"];
  $result=mysql_query("select movieid,mvenue FROM movievenue where mvenue='$movie' ");
  while($venue=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   echo"<option value=$venue[mvenue]>$venue[mvenue]</option>";

 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 include "db.php";

  $movie=$_POST["movie"];
  $result=mysql_query("select movieid,mvenue FROM movievenue where mvenue='{$movie['movieid']}' ");
  while($venue=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   echo"<option value=$venue[mvenue]>$venue[mvenue]</option>";

 }
?>
```

also, in your first file you probably want the select value to be the id of the movie

```
 echo "<option value=$movie[movieid]>$movie[moviename]</option>";
```